# Как убрать сообщение от Галереи?

Tags: java, android

При попытке взять фото из галереи, в мое активити, выскакивает сообщение:"Загрузка новых альбомов и фотографий". Как запретить вывод этого сообщения? Галерею вызываю следующим образом:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
```

---

Что бы напрямую получить доступ к галерее - стоит добавить параметром ее провайдер.

Comment: Не помогло. При возврате результата все равно возникает сообщение: "Загрузка новых альбомов и фотографий"